# Does Zalenium have plan to support other browser like IE, Edge? As per my understanding, currently it supports Chrome and Firefox only

Tags: selenium, browser-support, zalenium

As per my understanding, currently Zalenium supports Chrome and Firefox only. Does Zalenium have plan to support other browsers like IE, Edge too? If yes, is there any roadmap or timeline on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The project's [github](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium) says Zalenium is not being developed anymore. Link to github is on https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/ where, to confirm browsers support, it says you can run tests in Firefox and Chrome and "If you need a different browser, Zalenium can redirect your tests to a cloud testing provider (Sauce Labs, BrowserStack, TestingBot, CrossBrowserTesting, LambdaTest)".